# Basic Switch Error

Tags: ios, switch-statement, swift2

I am new to programming in Swift and I am taking a basic online course to teach me the syntax. On one of the courses on classes, it asked me to do this:

*2a. Add a type property to the Peach class called "varieties". It should hold an array of different types of peaches.*

*2b. Add an instance method called ripen() that increases the value of the stored property, softness, and returns a string indicating whether the peach is ripe.*

*2c. Create an instance of the Peach class and call the method ripen().*

It's not that hard. For the ripen function, I decided to use a switch control statement, with 3 being the optimal ripeness, 1 and 2 being too hard, 4 and 5 being overripe.

```
class Peach {
    let variety: String
    static let varieties = ["Bonita", "Cardinal", "Frost", "Golden"]

    var softness: Int

    init(variety: String, softness: Int) {
        self.variety = variety
        self.softness = 0
    }

    func ripen(softness: Int) -> String {

    softness ++

        switch softness {

        case 1, 2 :
            return "Not ready yet"
        case 3:
            return "Ripe"
        case 4,5:
            return "Over ripe"
        default:
            return "Gross"
        }
    }
}
```

On the line with the switch, this returns the error: **Expected expression after operator**. Looking at the color formatting, it appears that my code isn't treating the variable properly. So, how do I fix this error and what exactly does it mean? I'm sure this is a simple error that only a beginner would make, so I appreciate your patience in helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem starts with `softness ++`. You have to get rid of that space. But when you do that, it's going to complain that `softness` parameter to `ripen` is immutable. You probably should just remove the parameter to `ripen`, in which case it will know you wanted to increment the `softness` property.

```
class Peach {
    let variety: String
    static let varieties = ["Bonita", "Cardinal", "Frost", "Golden"]

    var softness: Int

    init(variety: String, softness: Int) {
        self.variety = variety
        self.softness = 0
    }

    func ripen() -> String {
        softness++

        switch softness {

        case 1, 2 :
            return "Not ready yet"
        case 3:
            return "Ripe"
        case 4,5:
            return "Over ripe"
        default:
            return "Gross"
        }
    }
}
```

Personally, I might be inclined to define `variety` as an `enum`:

```
class Peach {
    enum Variety {
        case Bonita
        case Cardinal
        case Frost
        case Golden
    }

    let variety: Variety

    var softness: Int

    init(variety: Variety, softness: Int) {
        self.variety = variety
        self.softness = 0
    }

    ...
}
```